# Rpi 3b+ No Display 7inch TFT-LCD Composite Display

Tags: pi-3b+, lcd, composite-video

[image: TFT LCD display]

I have 7 inch display which I used in my car almost 10 years back I want to use it with my Rpi3b+. I tried changing various display modes in config.txt like sdtv mode =0 and other numbers. None of them are working. Sometimes screen blinks but it doesn't work.
This display has two video inputs and works with 12v seperate power supply.
[image: power supply and inputs]
I am using composite cable for connecting rpi to this display.
[image: Composite Cable]

I tested with various tutorials like press shift key until green light stops blinking then press 1 2 3 4 which will redirect output to composite. It didn't work.
I tried hdmi_ignore_hotplug=1

None of these are working.
Can somebody guide me how to make it work.
TFT LCD works perfectly with my analog camera.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) 3 conventions for the adapter cable, most commonly available unsuitable.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/50995/8697

NOTE `tvservice` does not work on Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye.